# Change Sample Result Save Configuration for Sumary Report with jmeter maven

Tags: maven, jmeter, maven-plugin, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-maven-plugin

I have a JMX project with a "Sample Result Save Configuration" for "Sumary Report" as reported in the attached picture. And that JMX project is executed with Jmeter Maven plugin.
Now I would handle dynamically the Configuration of report from maven. For example I would unset the option "Save URL" not by Jmeter GUI mode. But I would set it during the execution of project by maven.
How it can be done?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWahI.png)

The related XML piece is as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81oXu.png)

Answer (score 0):

Changing JMeter listeners configuration is not something you can do with the JMeter Maven plugin, at least not with the [current version 3.7.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lazerycode.jmeter/jmeter-maven-plugin/3.7.0)

What you can do is to remove your Listeners (moreover it's [not recommended to use them for anything but test development and/or debugging](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean)) and use [JMeter Properties which are responsible for what's being stored in the .jtl results file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)

In this case you will be able to override the default setup like:

```
<configuration>
    <propertiesUser>
        <jmeter.save.saveservice.url>false</jmeter.save.saveservice.url>
    </propertiesUser>
</configuration>
```

Other properties can be overriden in exactly the same manner.

More information:

- [How to Use the JMeter Maven Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-maven-plugin)
- [JMeter Maven Plugin - Modifying Properties](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Modifying-Properties#5)

Comment: Good. That should be the right option I need. I would try to passe the boolean variable with a parameter as input . Thanks

Comment: I would add between the results also the details of username. Working with Jmeter to allow the same I added it in bin/user.properties the key=value : sample_variables=username

Do you know how add the related properties for the username also with jmeter maven configuration? For example has sense to add in pom.xml something similar the following?_

 <configuration>
     <propertiesUser>
          <jmeter.save.saveservice.username>false</jmeter.save.saveservice.username>
     </propertiesUser>
 </configuration>